# Varnish allow purge from any IPs

Tags: linux, caching, varnish, purge

I have a varnish cache server. I want to allow only three hosts can Purge a url or domain. I use the following varnish config for purging as the official web sites says:

```
    backend web_servers {
        .host = "192.168.1.20";
        .port = "80";
        .probe = backend_healthcheck;
    }


    acl purge {
            "localhost";
            "192.168.1.0"/24;
            "PUBLIC_IP";            
    }    

    sub vcl_recv {

        if (req.method == "PURGE")
            {
                    if (!client.ip ~ purge)
                    {
                            return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
                    }
                    return (purge);
            }
## Rest of vcl_recv
}
```

The problem is that I can purge a url from any IP address when executing the following curl command:

```
curl -X PURGE "domain_name.com"
```

I want only the IPs listed in purge section can purge a url from the admin port 6082 Not any other IPs from port 80. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. A stupid mistake. My varnish server is behind a proxy so, all IPs are 127.0.0.1 when I use "client.ip" to check the allowed IP addresses. I removed ACL purge and replaced the following lines :

```
if (!client.ip ~ purge)
{
    return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
}
return (purge);
```

with these ones:

```
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For == "PUBLIC_IP, 127.0.0.1" || req.http.X-Forwarded-For == "192.168.1.2, 127.0.0.1")
{
    return (purge);
}
return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
```

and now everything is working just fine.